# How can I calculate this sum?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm confused about how to evaluate this sum.

[image]

It looks complicated to me but I should know how to calculate it......thank you.

Comment: Note that the summand (the thing being summed) does not actually depend on $i$, so the sum is just the number of terms multiplied by the value of all of the terms. (This might be a typo, you may have wanted $\frac{1}{i}$ instead of $\frac{1}{n}$).

Comment: oh, so it's just a constant?

Comment: @Ian yes that is what is confusing me.  I didn't know what to do with the $n$ in the summand...so I can take out the whole summand and add up 1, (n-1) times? and get for an answer the summand times (n-1)?

Comment: Yes, because all $n-1$ terms are identical.

Comment: @Ian it makes sense, thank you!

Comment: The question discrimination of some people on this site is just too much.........

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\sum_\limits{i=1}^n \left( -2 \times\frac {1}{n} + 3\times \frac {1}{n}\right)$

First we can add the fractions together.

$\sum_\limits{i=1}^{n-1} \frac {1}{n}$

Since $\frac {1}{n}$ does not depend on $i$ we can factor that out. Not entirely necessary, but it should make it a little more clear.

$\frac 1n \sum_\limits{i=1}^{n-1} 1$

$\sum_\limits{i=1}^{n-1} 1 = n-1$

$\frac 1n \sum_\limits{i=1}^{n-1} 1 = \frac {n-1}{n}$